# Pivot without using an aggregate function to show all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a SQL table and given below is an image  of it.

[image]

I need to use tablet names as column names and show below in rows their times.
There are three distinct tablets and each has its own primary key.

Example column name augmenten and in this column shows all times of key 157.
I want something like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some thing like below

```
select [157],[158],[159] from
(
  select 
     koy, dateonly, time, 
     row_number() over(partition by koy order by dateonly desc,time desc) as ranking
from t
)s
pivot 
(
  max(time) for koy in ([157],[158],[159])
)p
```

The out put it gives me is below
[image]

Reference queries used:

```
create table t(koy int, tablet varchar(10), [time] time,dayz varchar(20),dateOnly date);
insert into t values 
(157,'A','13:27:36 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(157,'A','13:28:06 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(157,'A','13:28:36 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(158,'P','15:25:11 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(158,'P','15:25:41 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(158,'P','15:26:11 PM','Sat','03/12/2016'),
(159,'P','23:26:11 PM','Sat','03/12/2016')
```